# Form with many checkboxes, how to get a list of id's?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form, each row has a checkbox on it like:

```
<input type=checkbox id="cb-<%= o.ID %>" name="mycheckboxes" />
```

When the form is posted to an action, how can I get a list of the checked checkbox's id values?

Is it possible since they all have the same name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the value in the `value` attribute of the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<%= o.ID %>" name="mycheckboxes" />
```

In your action, tell ASP.NET MVC to look for an `int[]` with the name "mycheckboxes":

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int[] mycheckboxes)
{
   // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: By using cb-<%= o.ID %> as a Value, you'll need to change your method to use String instead of Integer.

Comment: @Guilherme - Good catch. I changed my answer and took out the `cb-` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking in javascript 
then Yes, use document.getElementsByName('') to get the list of all the checkbox and iterate thru them in the loop to find if its checked and get the ID.